# GA4 Debug View Value Array Problem [Ecommerce tracking with Google Tag Manager for GA4]

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am following this tutorial on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mNZQV7wFFo&t=601s
How to implement ecommerce tracking with Google Tag Manager for GA4.

The problem is that the items value come as [object Object] in GA4 debug view and not the data sent from GTM.

I have attached the photos.

Why do my GA4 seem to have a problem with the items? The other values are coming correctly.

[Data layer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moa2I.png)

[Tag fired, GTM correct values image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkQ5h.png)

[Tag using tutorial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2FbO.png)

[Data layer variable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6wQZ.png)

[GA4 debug view problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljz3q.png)

Answer (score 1):

Relayed your question to the measure community since it piqued my interest.

The array name is supposed to be items, not Items.

And you seem to be missing currency.